# What am I doing wrong here with .not()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var jobRole = $("select[name='location']").val();

$( "select[name='location']" )
    .change(function () {
       jobRole = $(this).val();
       $('#hiddenList li').appendTo('.content');
       $('.content li').not('+ jobRole').appendTo('#hiddenList');
       $('#PBANK_searchResult').pajinate();
       alert(jobRole);
});
```

If Edinburgh is select ".Edinburgh" appears as an alert ( I done this to check). However I was expeting that .Edinburgh would appear in the not() and resemble something like this:

```
$('.content li').not('.Edinburgh').appendTo('#hiddenList');
```

If I hardcord Edinburgh in to this the rest of the function works but I really need it to a variable depending on what is selected in the select box.

Thanks for your time

Comment: +1 For not blaming jQuery like "jQuery not working!" :D

Comment: can you share the related html

Comment: Can't you simply use the variable? `.not("." + jobRole)`?

Comment: looks like `jobRole` is a variable in `$('.content li').not('+ jobRole')` but you are using it as a string literal

Comment: is `jobRole` a class name/value etc

Comment: You need to concate jobRole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***the variable already has the .***

You need to use

```
$('.content li').not(jobRole).appendTo('#hiddenList');
```

Here `jobRole` is a variable so you don't need that in quotes

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment the variable already has the . all I need to do is add the variable in to the not()

Comment: Thank you I have no idea why I thought I should have had the + ... getting late in the day. Cant accept answer for 10 minutes though

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like this to use a variable

```
  $('.content li').not('.'+ jobRole).appendTo('#hiddenList');
  //                   ^^^^^^
```

**Update** *newInfo*

```
  $('.content li').not(jobRole).appendTo('#hiddenList');
  //                   ^^^^^^ no quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `jobRole` within the string selector - just a typo:

```
$('.content li').not('+ jobRole').appendTo('#hiddenList');

$('.content li').not(jobRole).appendTo('#hiddenList'); 
//Since you say the jobRole includes the '.' for the class selector
```